# Running/debugging project in Rider will not open browser window

Tags: rider, .net-4.7.2

When I run/debug a project in Rider, I have somehow turned off the property that opens the browser window after the project has built successfully. I have checked `Run > Edit Configurations` and compared it against an API project I have that *does* open the browser when ran/debugged, and cannot see a difference. I did some searching online and didn't find a definitive answer, so I'm reaching out here.

If anyone knows the specific property/setting/whatever to toggle in order to get the browser to open when running/debugging the project, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While examining the `Run/Debug` configs between the project that wasn't doing the expected behavior and the API project that was, I noticed that in the non-working project's `Run/Debug` config, the URL property wasn't set. After setting that to the localhost value I had been using, the page would start up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what it looks like for one of our projects targeting .NET Framework 4.8:
[image]